# System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format (gRPC asp.net Core)

Tags: c#, sql-server, grpc, guid

I'm trying to get a User By is Id

The problem is in gRPC don't exist 'Guid' so I need to put the proto something like this

```
service UserAuth {
  
  //...

  rpc Delete (UserFilter) returns (Empty);

}

//messages...

message Empty{}

message UserFilter{ string userID = 1; }
```

And in my database, the Id has a form of a Guid

So how to get the 'user' by is Id since in the database I have the Id in type Guid and the UserFilter (which is a simple string in my request)

I try this but gives me a lot of errors like 'System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format' or the line gives me null (which its incorrect)

I will show the Delete method in gRPC

```cs
public override async Task<Empty> Delete(UserFilter requestData,
                ServerCallContext context)
{
    var guid = new Guid(requestData.UserID);

    //var data = await _context.Users_5.Where(x => x.Id.ToString() == requestData.UserID);
    var data = _context.Users_5.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(guid)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (data == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("User Not Found");
    }
    _context.Users_5.Remove(data!);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return await Task.FromResult(new Empty());
}
```

Edit: Values of my inputs

Guid -> Something like this -> 8D84C24F-C83B-4FE0-54B9-08DA43CF8A29

In the Model I have a User.cs with the Id like this

```cs
[Key]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

Edit ++ :

I put the code work but I think its a bad idea,

This is what I did, I have other method that calls this one and in that method I use a cookie to pass the Id to the 'UserFilter'

In the gRPC I use this

```cs
var guid = Guid.Parse(requestData.UserID.ToString());

var data = _context.Users_5.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(guid)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Still its not the best way to do this but resolves my problem, if you have a better idea pls tell me how do to that

Comment: you show setting userID = 1. 1 is not a guid. And its also not a string.

Comment: @Ralf that's a protobuf schema; that isn't the *instance data* - that just means "there exists a field with key `1` is called `userID` of type `string`" - it is a type definition, not an object initialization expression (the 1 is not a value)

Comment: The userID is a string, how it cannot be a string? This is gRPC and in gRPC you need to show the messages like this format

Comment: @JoséLeal so at runtime: what *is* the actual value received for `requestData.UserID` ? can we see that? for any normal value, `new Guid(string)` should work, so: to understand why it isn't, it would really help to see the value that is being passed. The page here lists the accepted guid formats for that usage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.-ctor#system-guid-ctor(system-string)

Comment: Also: can I assume that `x.Id` is of type `Guid`, and that in the database the column is defined as `uniqueidentifier` ?

Comment: Ye, check the edit @Marc Gravell

Comment: @JoséLeal something *like* `"8D84C24F-C83B-4FE0-54B9-08DA43CF8A29"`, or *actually* that? because that value: works fine; what is the actual value *when it doesn't work*?

Comment: Or gives me null or gives me System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format. What do you mean when a guid "doesn't work"?

Comment: @JoséLeal I mean the bit where you say "I try this but gives me a lot of errors like 'System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format' " - ok: show us the value that produces that outcome. As for the DB returning null: that suggests that there isn't a row with that value. So: assuming you can get past the guid parse step, and checking *very carefully* to make sure you're looking at the same database and the correct table: *is* there a row with a value that you're trying? we can't answer that, as we can't see the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245391/discussion-between-jose-leal-and-marc-gravell).